# Firebase data payload size limitation MessageTooBig

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

Dears, Slam.
I'm using firebase notification utility with it's Data payload.
The problem is in Data Payload size.
in FireBase Documentation "a total message size limit of 4kb."

```js
{
    "to" : "/topics/global",
    "notification": {
        "body": "Cool Tractor",
        "title": "Flat 80% discount",
        "icon": "appicon"
    },
    "data" : {
  "type":"2",
  "title":"New Machinery added",
  "message":"Dal Eng add new tractor to crops list, please check",
  "equip":{
  "equip_name":"Taf Tractor N900",
  "equip_type":"T",
  "equip_spec":"Very strog tractor..................................like batman",
  "equip_name_ar":"تركتر البعاعيت للشغل العتيد",
  "equip_type_ar":"تركتر",
  "equip_spec_ar":"التركر دا جااامد جدا جدا جدا وبشتغل شغل عنيف",
  "equip_img_url":"droid-life.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/lollipop-wallpapers10.jpg",
  "equip_pdf_url":"dalgroup.com",
  "equip_vid_url":"youtube.com",
  "equip_text":"<p><strong>Land preperation0101</strong></p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te sumo latine nusquam sed, ex his vidisse vocibus, ut mea habemus perfecto efficiantur. His ludus volutpat ad, pri tempor adipisci ex. Vim ea ferri decore similique, an decore minimum definiebas est, habeo mollis usu ne. Suas dicit ad sed, aliquam appareat intellegebat mea ne. An lucilius incorrupte cum, altera splendide usu ei.</div><div>&nbsp;</div><div>Usu ne facer veritus definitiones, debet vulputate per id. Sit omnes decore facilisi ad. No animal officiis reformidans vel, nonumy facilisi inimicus te mea, nam solum posse eirmod te. Ius nisl affert placerat ad.</div><div>&nbsp;</div><div>Ne paulo intellegam definitiones sea, an enim assum vituperata eum. Posse saepe usu an, eu reprimique scripserit adversarium est, ne honestatis concludaturque vis. Dicant constituam pri ea, stet admodum no qui. Modo facete id vis.</div><div>&nbsp;</div><div>Ex oratio voluptatum his, ei vel causae disputando. At quo aeque audire vivendo. Sumo minim his ut. Qui paulo probatus te, at iudico molestie pro. Errem principes id per, eos cu verterem iracundia, cum graece disputando an.</div><div>&nbsp;</div><div>Ex nam tempor deterruisset, rebum scripserit qui id, soleat regione eum cu. Voluptua adipiscing ex nec. Eu cum nobis eripuit invidunt, ne tota molestiae nec. Magna possim ancillae ius ea, eam et dicat inani errem, est eros nominati ut.</div>",
  "equip_text_ar":"<p><strong>Cool Tractor</strong></p><p><em>ractors</em> and Farm Equipment Limited 77, Nungambakkam High Road, ... and Farm Equipment Limited Managed by <em>TAFE</em> Corporate Communications. <em>tafe</em>-tribe.</p>"
  
>     }
>   }
>}
```

**Text above is my request**

it's size about 2K

so why firebase fcm say message Too Big

Comment: Well, it is true that you can send up to 4KB, so make sure or doble check that the size of your payload is less than 4KB. From this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref), the error:MessageTooBig means that you exceed the 4096 byte. Also, you can try to check this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) on how to send messages to topics.

Comment: i had checked the document. and i post my request above, if you take the request and get it's size it won't reach 4K...